# Boosting an Instagram Post through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I've been going through the FB API docs for hours and can't seem to find the the right approach to "boosting" or promoting an Instagram post.

I have a page-linked Instagram business account, and I've been trying to create an ad creative (to then create a campaign, adset, and ad). However, I'm not sure what the parameters I should be using.

For the the adcreative request creation request I'm not sure how to set it for an Instagram post. The fields I'm currently using are:

name: 'Testing Instagram Ad',
object_story_id: ,
instagram_actor_id: <(INSTAGRAM PAGE ID)_INSTAGRAM_POST_ID)>

I am getting invalid parameters as an error response.

Comment: I think you need to use  the Instagram API: from the facebook API you can Boost a FB post on Instagram as platform (I don't think you can do the inverse) But I'm curious about to know if is possible!

Comment: I have the same issue, can you share your solution with us? :)

Comment: It's not possible (as of now) to boost an Instagram post. You can create a Facebook post and boost on both Facebook and Instagram.